# Utilizar função de uma pasta externa

Tags: python

Tenho a seguinte situação:

- Dentro da `Pasta1\` eu tenho um arquivo que é meu código principal
- Este arquivo `codigo_principal.py` lê um arquivo que está em uma subpasta dentro da `Pasta1\`
- Tenho também outra pasta, `Pasta2`, e dentro dela eu tenho um codigo, `teste.py`
- O arquivo `teste.py` precisa usar a função do arquivo `codigo_principal.py` que lê `Sub_pasta1\arquivo.txt`

Segue a estrutura das pastas:

```
Pasta1/
    Sub_pasta1/
        arquivo.txt
    codigo_principal.py
Pasta2/
    teste.py
```

O problema já surgiu quando eu precisava fazer o import deste arquivo de uma pasta diferente, consegui contornar este problema usando o módulo `imp`

Eu consigo usar todos os recursos do `codigo_principal.py`, mas a função que lê o `arquivo.txt` não funciona por que ele tenta buscar esse arquivo dentro da `Pasta2\SubPasta1\arquivo.txt`.

EDIT: Eu estou usando e preciso usar o caminho relativo, não posso usar o absoluto

Este é o código que estou usando no `teste.py`

```
import imp

wtf=imp.load_source("codigo_principal", "../Pasta1/codigo_principal.py")
wtf.funcao_le_arquivo()
```

Mas desta forma eu recebo a mensagem de erro:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: Sub_pasta1/arquivo.txt

Comment: Você está usando o caminho absoluto para abrir o arquivo? Se for o relativo, o caminho passa a ser relativo ao diretório `Pasta2`, buscando por `Pasta2/Sub_pasta1/arquivo.txt`.

Comment: Havia esquecido de citar, eu preciso usar o caminho relativo

Comment: Então entre com o caminho como parâmetro da função e no arquivo `teste.py` você define o caminho relativo à `Pasta2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta apenas transformar a pasta1 em um pacote python, colocando um arquivo vazio com o nome `__init__.py`, a partir dai basta fazer o import das funcoes que vc deseja desse pacote.

### Exemplo com Hello World:

Crie uma pasta chamada projeto, dentro dela crie a pasta1 e a pasta2, dentro da pasta1, crie um arquivo vazio com o nome `__init__.py` para que essa pasta se torne um "package" e, nessa mesma pasta, crie o codigo principal. Na pasta2 crie o arquivo teste que vai chamar a função do codigo principal. Veja abaixo a figura da estrutura das pastas e, em seguida, o código.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**projeto/pasta1/main_code.py**

```
def hello():
    print ('Hello World')
```

**projeto/pasta2/teste.py**

```
from pasta1.main_code import hello

hello()
```

**Output:**

```
Hello World

Process finished with exit code 0
```