# Como criar módulo python e disponibilizar para qualquer aplicação

Tags: python

gostaria que meu programa em python pudesse ser posto no sistema de tal forma que com um simples `import` ele possa ser executado, como por exemplo:

```
import meucodigo
meucodigo.main()
```

O meu código contém diversos arquivos (módulos próprios) e todos são chamados através da classe main.

A ideia é que com isso eu possa criar um instalador para que ele configure tudo corretamente para o usuário final. Pretendo usar o [install creator 2](https://www.clickteam.com/install-creator-2) e assim o user possa chama-lo após a instalação. Lembrando que preciso que seja um instalador como o citado. Alguma dica?

Sei que é possível, mas infelizmente não encontro nenhum tutorial que ensine.

OBS: Uso e preciso usar o python 2.5.

Comment: Para criar seus proprios packages em python veja [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/215549/7412) e para "empacotar" sua app em um instalador, [veja essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/216077/7412), aqui no STOpt.

Comment: A maneira que está sendo ensinado no link 1 eu já utilizo, no entanto, gostaria que todo o meu código pudesse ser importado por outro programa, sendo chamado em qualquer parte do sistema operacional.

Comment: Então o que vc quer é criar e distribuir seus pacotes, vc pode publicar no PyPI ou em um servidor proprio, é bem extenso para colocar uma resposta aqui, [comece por aqui](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/), se tiver dificuldades com o ingles, [tente uma busca no google assim](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=como+criar+pacote+python+no+PyPi&oq=como+criar+pacote+python+no+PyPi&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.13911j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Vi essa possibilidade, mas como eu disse, gostaria de que fosse configurado através de um instalador, pois o script criado é proprietário e precisa ser rodado por outro programa chamado ArcGIS. Entende?! Um tempo atrás eu vi um video que ensinava basicamente isso mas infelizmente não encontrei mais. Mas obrigado pela dica!

Comment: Nada impede de vc configure e instale um pacote atraves de um instalador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie a seguinte estrutura de pastas:

```
MeuCodigo\
   README
   LICENSE
   setup.py
   meucodigo\
       __init__.py
       meucodigo.py
```

Dentro de setup.py coloque o seguinte:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(name='MeuCodigo', version='0.1', author='Edeson Bizerril',
    author_email='edeson@bizerril.com', 
    url='http://bizerril.com/meucodigo',
    packages=['meucodigo'],
)
```

Dentro de `__init__.py` coloque o seguinte:

```
from .meucodigo import *
```

Dentro de `meucodigo.py` coloque o seguinte:

```
def main():
     # codigo aqui
def .... # outras funções etc
```

Em seguida abra um prompt de comando, vá até a pasta `MeuCodigo` e digite:

```
C:\MeuCodigo> py setup.py bdist_wininst
```

Com isso será gerado um executável instalador em `MeuCodigo\dist\MeuCodigo-0.1.exe`

Você pode usar também:

```
C:\MeuCodigo> py setup.py bdist_msi
```

Para gerar o instalador em formato msi `MeuCodigo-0.1.msi`.

Veja mais sobre o assunto na [documentação do `distutils`](https://docs.python.org/library/distutils.html).

Comment: O meu principal interesse é que ele possa ser chamado através do comando `import meucodigo` por qualquer programa ou terminal. É possível após essa instalação?

Comment: @EdesonBizerril sim, qualquer programa ou terminal que esteja rodando o `python` é claro. `import meucodigo` não é comando válido em powershell ou CMD do windows.

Comment: Tive os seguinte erro: 
`C:\Users\Edeson Bizerril\Desktop\meu_teste>py setup.py bdist_wininst
'py' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.`
O meu python instalado não é o padrão, mas sim um que veio instalado com o programa ArcGIS no diretório: `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5`

Comment: @EdesonBizerril `py` é o [lançador do python para windows](https://docs.python.org/3.3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) talvez não esteja no seu `PATH` por isso não está achando. Tente especificar o caminho completo para o seu python, por exemplo, digite: `C:\Python37\python.exe setup.py bdist_wininst` (se o seu python estiver instalado em `C:\Python37`)

Comment: Deu muito certo. A ultima pergunta: Fiz o teste com um único arquivo, mas caso eu tenha vários diretórios e arquivos ele fará a instalação corretamente?

Comment: @EdesonBizerril sim, desde que todos estejam dentro do seu `package` (pasta meucodigo)  e todos os packages estejam corretamente especificados no `setup.py`. Existem parâmetros também para especificar a instalação de arquivos adicionais que não sejam código python, entre outras funções úteis. Leia a documentação do distutils.